# claws mail how to get system mails over exim4

Tags: debian, email, exim

OS = debian stretch mate desktop with

```
claws-mail --version
Claws Mail version 3.14.1
```

Is there a way to create an account for system mails so I can get them in claws-mail (like for apt-listchanges) over exim4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `/etc/aliases` file.
In standard configuration

- email to all system accounts is redirected to `root`
- emai to `root` is redirected to non privileged OS account.

Comment: @ AnFi that was usefull. Do you know how I can separate the 2 accounts? I get both e-mails (provider and from exim4) in the same inbox folder.

Comment: You can alias root to user+root (+detail) and **as I understand** use $local_part_suffix in exim filter (~/.forward file). [I do not use exim myself]

Comment: I'm an idiot I only have to control the default inbox folder in claws-mail for this account. thank's.